# visual studio code multiple instances error

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

[image]

The setup is keep on showing me notifications as shown above. I am not even able to open the app for now. Whenever I open this notification keeps on popping up and many tabs of the apps are opening as shown in the image above. Please help me to resolve this problem.

I deleted the setup file of the Visual Studio Code. I downloaded it again and installed it again. I thought it would work properly after that, but it didnt.

Comment: Have you tried just killing all running instances of the VS Code process in task manager?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150330

Comment: yes but even after killing them again new ones are popping up.